# Date only comparison c#

Tags: c#

I must be going crazy, but I'm comparing 2 DateTime object's Date parts... and for some reason this is returning false?? I'm really stumped...

[DateTime Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWuzR.png)

Either I'm doing something horribly wrong or i'm missing something massive... I've made sure these are both DateTime objects, and they are both 16/09/2020.

That's pretty much all I've tried so far. I didn't think there's another way or that this wouldn't have worked..

Full line is:

```
bool isequal = CActivity.Instance.SignInOuts[0].Date == signInOut.Date;
```

SignInOut is `SignInOut signInOut = new SignInOut();` where I'm assigning the date, and `CActivity.Instance.SignInOuts` is defined here:

```
public class SignInOut
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan SignInTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan SignOutTime { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Maybe use .Equals()

Comment: wait let me test that on the RHS too as I only tested it on the LHS.. lol.. this is why you shouldn't code at 2:30am...

Comment: yeah works now... Date.Date... and Date.Date.... I need to rename that to something more sensible... and go sleep.... thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referencing a property called `Date`, that is a `DateTime`.  You want to compare the property *on* the DateTime, so do:

```
bool isequal = CActivity.Instance.SignInOuts[0].Date.Date == signInOut.Date.Date;
```

Comment: Thanks Jonesopolis. True say... I'm clearly too tired coding this late... I'll accept it when the 7 minutes pass - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime` and `TimeSpan` are both the same size: 8 bytes.  From a storage and simplicity standpoint, I don't think there's much reason to store a point in time as `DateTime + TimeSpan` when you could just use a `DateTime`.  Thus, you could store the same information more clearly with only two properties...

```cs
public class SignInOut
{
    public DateTime SignInTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime SignOutTime { get; set; }
}
```

Not only would that eliminate the awkward usage of `signInOut.Date.Date` (because `SignInOut.Date`, counter to its name, evidently has a non-zero `TimeOfDay` component) and simplify the class/calculations by storing the date/time pairs directly, it would also support the scenario where the sign-in and sign-out didn't take place on the same day (better than `signInOut.SignOutTime.Ticks` being `> TimeSpan.TicksPerDay`).

You would still have to write something like...

```cs
bool isequal = CActivity.Instance.SignInOuts[0].SignInTime.Date == signInOut.SignInTime.Date;
```

...to do a date-only comparison, but it makes the oversight that caused this question a lot less likely.